# Can I post a similar question when I make a mistake?

Tags: support

I posted a question some hours ago:

[How can we prove that $D(f)\backsimeq\operatorname{Spec} A_f$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492327/how-can-we-prove-that-df-backsimeq-operatornamespec-a-f/492425?noredirect=1#492425)

I realized I made a stupid mistake, instead of asking the injectivity of the map, I asked how to prove that this one is surjectivity.

So I'm in a dilemma, I don't know if I repost the question without the error or I edit it. The problem is the question has already answers, if I change it I think the post wouldn't make any sense.

Thanks.

Comment: One of the thing to consider is whether your question was already answered, such situation was discussed for example [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561/can-i-change-the-existing-question-to-a-new-one). You will find several related discussion in the questions linked to that one.

Comment: [I did](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/459773/19341), as adviced [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10531/19341)...